# Read CSV File and Store Column in list double

Tags: c#, csv

carry the code below where I embarked.

```
class readFile{

        List<double> out1 = new List<double>();
        List<double> out2 = new List<double>();
        List<double> out3 = new List<double>();

 public readFile()
        {

        }

        public void aproCSV()
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\altraprova.csv"));

            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var values = line.Split(';');

                out1.Add(values[0]);
                out2.Add(values[1]);
                out3.Add(values[2]);
            }
        }
}
```

Allow me to explain my intent ....

I open my csv file

the goal is to read the second column and insert it into a list of type double and then get the value MAX.

If you use lists of type string not get erors .... but since the values contain only numbers you are signed semicolon, then I need to use the type double.. using the double type get the following error:

> error 5 The best match of the overloaded method for
>   `'System.Collections.Generic.List <double> .Add (double)'` has some
>   invalid arguments

Comment: Use a parser like kbcsv - it#s way easier and more robust than crafting your own

Comment: After you've successfully parsed the strings to double you can use `out1.Max()` to get the maximum value.

Answer (score 1):

[`Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a `string[]` and your lists are of type `List<double>` which means you need to parse the strings into doubles like the following:

`double value1 = double.Parse(values[0]);` etc

then add them to your list: `out1.Add(value1);`

Do be aware that you have no error handling so if the value is not a double, the code will still throw an `exception`.

Comment: I updated the code as follows: 'code'  public void aproCSV()
        {

            
            var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\altraprova.csv"));
            
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var values = line.Split(';');

                ///out1.Add(value1[0]);
                double value1 = double.Parse(out1[0]);
                out1.Add(value1);
                out2.Add(values[1]);
                out3.Add(values[2]);
            }
        }

Comment: @Ric: I think it is better not to parse a csv oneself. For instance if the comma occurs in a string: `'foo,bar',column2`, the comma is part of a string. Of course one can handle some cases, but the a library will in many cases contain less bugs.

Comment: I agree, I never do it without a library like `LinqToCsv` - the number of time's I've been caught out by things in the past as per your comment only reinforce the use of a good csv reader.

Answer (score 1):

CSV are surprisingly not so straightforward to parse, there are a lot of special cases which you have to take into consideration. For example, if your data would contain the "separation character" you'd need to put the data between quotes ("). If he contains quotes, then you have to escape them with a backslash (\) (or doubling them, I'm not sure).

So, except if you know the data you're going to be importing and are sure that those case won't happen, a simple "split" won't be sufficient.

I really recommend using an existing parser to help you on this task. I've used [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) with success. It's a nice library and quite easy to use.

Comment: CsvHelper looks quite good, usually I go for `LinqToCsv` but I might try something different in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some parsing, because a generic list only accepts elements of the given type (double in your case):

```
var line = reader.ReadLine();
var values = line.Split(';');

out1.Add(double.Parse(values[0]));
out2.Add(double.Parse(values[1]));
out3.Add(double.Parse(values[2]));
```

This is the quick and dirty trick, you should use [double.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

for safety because maybe not everything you get is a double.
From you code I suppose the you need to get the max from list `out2` (your second column). For this, use [List.Max Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb909383%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I realized that the method reader.ReadLine() allows them to read for lines, I need the column...any idea?